Uploading geoip-lite to postgres
So if I want to use the geoip-lite database from maxmind and upload it to my postgres database to lookup, I'd convert the csv to json and then upload it the database or keep it as csv and upload if possible.
Do I just add an index on the main column and let query the database or is this inefficient?
I'm using Supabase. Is there an extension that makes it more performant or is an index sufficient? Or am I completely missing how to use this data?

Which columns to use in the index and what index type to pick depends on what type of queries you intend to speed up. The example index in their doc only speeds up queries based on the network column, and only using specific operators - it won't help querying based on lat/long or any other column. You could show some example queries you need to optimise this for.
